# How to divide a matrix along an axis in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

How to divide a matrix - or doing other arithmetic operations - along an axis with a vector in Matlab?

Example:

```
M = [2 4 6  ; ...
     8 4 2 ];

v = [2 4 2];

d = M/v;         % divide along first axis

d = 
     1 1 3
     4 1 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perfect setup for **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** with `@rdivide` option to let `v` internally expand to the size of `M` and then perform elementwise division -

```
d = bsxfun(@rdivide,M,v)
```

---

## Benchmarking on solutions

**Benchmarking Code**

```
N_arr = [100 200 500 1000 2000 4000];
timeall = zeros(4,numel(N_arr));
for k1 = 1:numel(N_arr)

    N = N_arr(k1);
    M = rand(N,N);
    v = rand(1,N);

    f = @() bsxfun(@rdivide,M,v);
    timeall(1,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f

    f = @() M ./ repmat(v, size(M, 1), 1);
    timeall(2,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f
    
    f = @() M ./ ( ones(size(M,1),1)*v );
    timeall(3,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f
    
    f = @() ele_div(M,v);
    timeall(4,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f
end
figure,hold on,grid on
plot(N_arr,timeall(1,:),'-ro'),plot(N_arr,timeall(2,:),'-kx')
plot(N_arr,timeall(3,:),'-g+'),plot(N_arr,timeall(4,:),'-b.')
legend('BSXFUN','REPMAT','ONES','FOR-LOOP'),
xlabel('Datasize ->'),ylabel('Time(sec) ->')
```

**Associated function**

```
function MM = ele_div(M,v)
MM = zeros(size(M));
for i=1:size(M,1)
    MM(i,:) = M(i,:) ./ v;
end
return;
```

**Benchmarking Results**

[image]

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah, who said `for-loops` aren't bad anymore! :)

Comment: I'm glad they are :-P

Answer (score 2):

Couple of ways:

```
%# FOR-loop
MM = zeros(size(M));
for i=1:size(M,1)
    MM(i,:) = M(i,:) ./ v;
end

%# BSXFUN
MM = bsxfun(@rdivide, M, v);

%# REPMAT
MM = M ./ repmat(v,size(M,1),1);

%# repetition by multiplication
MM = M ./ ( ones(size(M,1),1)*v );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `repmat` to make `v` the same dimension as `M`:

```
d = M ./ repmat(v, size(M, 1), 1)
```